# How is this F# workflow evaluated?

Tags: f#

I am fairly new to F# but have been reading about workflows and computation expressions. From the reading I have done, I thought I felt I had at least a basic understanding of the purpose of a workflow and the syntax for using a workflow. Then, I came across an example here: [BitWorker Workflow](https://theburningmonk.com/2014/10/f-imitating-erlangs-bit-syntax-for-easier-binary-protocol-implementation/).

I tried copying the example code to a local project and ran it successfully. I started moving things around and getting a feel for what the code did, but I am still having trouble understanding how this workflow actually works. I haven't seen other examples where the workflow syntax was like: `do bitWriter stream {...` instead of `do workflow {...`.

```
let stream = new IO.MemoryStream()

// write TCP headers
do bitWriter stream {
    do! BitWriter.WriteInt16(12345s)           // source port
    do! BitWriter.WriteInt16(12321s)           // destination port
    do! BitWriter.WriteInt32(1)                // sequence number
    do! BitWriter.WriteInt32(1)                // ack number
    do! BitWriter.WriteInt32(2, numBits = 4)   // data offset
    do! BitWriter.WriteInt32(0, numBits = 3)   // reserved
}
```

I wouldn't have expected `stream` to be a part of the `bitWriter` workflow. What does the use of `stream` here mean for the workflow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be easier to explain if we look at a minimal example that implements a workflow like this. First, I'll define a type for operations that you can do. For simplicity, let's have just one:

```
type Operation =  
  | WriteInt32 of int
```

Typical F# computation builders do not take any constructor parameters, but you can actually take parameters - the computation builder here takes a stream as a parameter and creates a `StreamWriter`. In the `Bind` operation, the argument is one of our `Operation` values and we handle that by writing the value to the stream writer. Then we just call the rest of the computation using `f ()`

```
type BitWriter(stream:IO.Stream) = 
  let wr = new IO.StreamWriter(stream)
  member x.Bind(op, f) = 
    match op with
    | WriteInt32 i -> wr.Write(i)
    f ()
  member x.Zero() = ()
  member x.Run( () ) = wr.Dispose()
```

The `Zero` and `Run` operations are not particularly interesting, but `Zero` is required by the translation and `Run` lets us dispose of the writer. This is not the most idiomatic way of definining computation expressions - it does not follow the monadic structure - but it actually works! Two helpers before we can use it:

```
let writeInt32 i = WriteInt32 i
let bitWriter stream = BitWriter(stream)
```

And now you can write code that is pretty much what the above library does:

```
let stream = new IO.MemoryStream()

bitWriter stream {
  do! writeInt32 1
  do! writeInt32 2
  do! writeInt32 3
}
```